# How do I remove this shower diverter knob?

Tags: plumbing, shower, bathtub, diverter

I’m trying to remove my tub hardware so I can replace the tub surround, but I’m stuck getting the diverter disassembled.

Every guide that I’ve found online says that the cap should pop off to expose a screw. That was true for the faucets but I can’t get the cap off the diverter despite prying behind the silver disc with a putty knife (I bent a butter knife trying too!). I’m concerned I’m doing the wrong thing and going to break the knob. Is there some other way these knobs are sometimes attached?

[image: photo of a three-spout shower diverter]

Comment: Putting a rag soaked in vinegar or a calcium dissolver like CLR™ around the diverter and letting it soak for a while may help. It could well be that it's just corroded on and that's fighting you more than any fancy attaching mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Take a small slotted screwdriver and insert in under the chrome top of the diverter knob and twist. You'll get more leverage twisting the screwdriver than a butter knife. The chrome top should pop off exposing a screw which you just have to unscrew

Answer (score 0):

I would start with using vinegar to clean and loosen.

The big outer is just a cosmetic cover.

Sometime held with small screw from underneath.

Cut the caulk between it and the wall.

If it does not comes out, next step would be to use pliers..

Remove the center nut part, that holds the catrige in place and maybe the big outer ring.

Based on the amount of clack it might take some force.